# Running webdriver.io from commandline to run tests on a microsoft vsts build

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines, webdriver-io, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Can anyone share how I might run a webdriver.io tests remotely from a vsts build as part of Continuous integration or continuous deployment? I'm thinking I can add a command line script to the build definition to run the tests.

I know I dont have an example here. But I have been searching for an answer. In need of help. Please.

Answer (score 0):

You can add command line script to run the test.

Note: The agent need to be run as interactive mode if the test need to to interactive with browser.